# Finding the lowest y point of screen bounds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using c# in unity and I need to calculate the lowest y position of the camera (2D) however I only know how to find the height i.e.

```
private Vector2 screenBounds;


void Start()
{
    screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));      
}


void Update()
{
    screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
    
    if (transform.position.y < screenBounds.y)
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

}

I am trying to use this code to despawn old objects.

Answer (score 1):

What you get is the **top-right** corner

> Screenspace is defined in pixels. The bottom-left of the screen is (0,0); the right-top is (pixelWidth,pixelHeight).

Also I assume your camera position is e.g. `z = -10` and you want a world point in front and not behind the camera

So if you want the bottom border you would rather use

```
screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3 (0, 0, -Camera.main.transform.position.z);
```

If your camera is **orthogonal** anyway then you don't have to care about the `z` at all and can just use

```
screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector2.zero);
```

---

In order to not have to calculate twice if you also want to check later if it is above the screen you could also go the other way round though which is often even easier:

```
// Other than the ScreenToWorldPoint here it doesn't matter whether 
// the camera is orthogonal or perspective or how far in front of the camera you want a position
// or if your camera is moved or rotated
var screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

if(screenPos.y < 0) Debug.Log("Below screen");
else if(screenPos.y > Screen.height) Debug.Log("Above screen");

if(screenPos.x < 0) Debug.Log("Left of screen");
else if(screenPos.x > Screen.width) Debug.Log("Right of screen");
```

---

However, using only the `transform.position` is a bit unreliable since you already would destroy objects that are still (half) visible.

Instead you could use [`GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html) to get the planes surrounding the actual camera frustum and then use [`GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html) to check wether your objects' [`Renderer.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) are actually **visible** to the camera like e.g.

```
Renderer _renderer;
Camera _camera;

void Update()
{
    if(!_renderer) _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    if(!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;

    var planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(_camera);

    if (!GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, _renderer.bounds))
    {
        Debug.Log($"\"{name}\" is outside of the screen!", this);

        // and e.g.
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to save the initial box the camera sees and use that as a boundary?

If that's the case then it's easy to do in 2D, but gets much more complex in 3D. So below is the 2D solution.

The camera is in the center of the viewport. Meaning that the top boundry is the Camera position plus half the height of the viewport.

```
// Get the camera height
float height = Screen.height;

// Now we get the position of the camera
float camY = Camera.Main.transform.position.y;

// Now Calculate the bounds
float lowerBound = camY + height / 2f;
float upperBound = camY - height / 2f;
```

Comment: No, be careful: the `camY` will be in world space coordinates while the `height` is in **pixel space** so this will return wrong values!

Comment: I understand that camY will be in world space, is that not what you are trying to achieve? Delete the camera if it goes too low in world space?

Comment: The idea is delete another object if it goes out of the screen. The problem is that your `lowerBound` will be `camY(worldSpace e.g. 2.5) - height(pixels e.g. 1080) / 2f` .. the result is way to low ;) You probably also wanted to exchange the signs because a lower bound would be a smaller value than an upper bound